# How to move UIScrollView up and down in response to change in a height value of a view?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Given a change in size of a view from `48` to `72`, and from `72` to `48`, how to move scroll view up and down accordingly?

Situation A: 
The view's height is 48.

```
[    ] a view
----- keyboard upper edge
```

Now the view changes its size from 48 to 72. And part of it (24 points) is hidden behind a keyboard.

```
[    ] a view
----- keyboard upper edge
[////] a view's part that got hidden.
```

Q1: How to move the scrollView up so the enlarged view is is not obscured by the keyboard?

---

Situation B: 
The view's height is 72.

```
[     ] a view
[     ]
------- keyboard upper edge
```

The view changes its size again. This time from 72 to 48.

```
[     ] a view
unwanted empty space
------  keyboard upper edge
```

Q2: How to move the scrollview down back to its position, so there is no unwanted empty space?

Answer (score 0):

From interface builder drag as **IBOulet** height constraint of the view that changes form 48 to 72 name it **viewHeightCon** also drag bottom constraint of the **scrollview** name it **scrollViewBottomCon**

```
   func changeTo48OR72 (value: Int)
   {

       // adjust view height here
       self.viewHeightCon.constant = value

         if(value == 72)
        {
           // make scrollview up sum of keyboard and 24 [72-48]
           self.scrollViewBottomCon.constant = -1 * (keyboardHeight + 24)
        }
        else if(value == 48)
        {
           // restore scrollview directly up keyboard
          self.scrollViewBottomCon.constant = -1* keyboardHeight
        } 


       // animate height change

       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

       })


   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this problem is not related to the keyboard showing up or getting hidden. But to the problem that a view gets larger, and when that happens the part of that view is hidden behind the keyboard, so the scrollview should be scrolled up a bit, so that that enlarged part of the view is visible again.

Comment: then change  scrollViewBottomCon to your ViewBottomCon

Comment: let me imagine your structure scollview at top then the view at middle then keyboard at bottom , right ????

Comment: I see it where is the ScrollView in that

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: answer this please so i can help you

Comment: I use auto layout. The view is part of the scrollView's content. The scrollview should be scrolled vertically up or down.

Comment: where is the scrollView in the scene is it contains the view that changes from 48 to 72 or that scrollView above it vertically ?????????

Comment: Sorry, but I might not fully understand what you are asking about. The view [    ] is part of the scrollView's content. The scrollview should be scrolled vertically up or down. The size of the view [    ] can change dynamically. However, the scroll view should react to that change by being scrolled up or down accordingly. Assume that the keyboard is always visible.

Comment: @ Balagurunathan Marimuthu comments added to explain steps